# Why are my Greek characters being inserted in the database as question marks(?) when using parameterized queries?

Tags: vb.net, prepared-statement, unicode-string, intersystems-cache

DBMS = Intersystem Cache'
Driver Version = 2018.1.2.309.5

The below is a sample of the code I'm using:

```vb
Dim strsql = "UPDATE TBLSTK SET ICDESC=? WHERE ITEMNO=27227" 

Using cmdsrv As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("", myConn)
    cmdsrv.CommandText = strsql
    cmdsrv.Parameters.Add("ICDESC", Odbc.OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = "2ΤΟ ΧΡΙΣΤ/ΚΟ ΔΕΝΤΡΟ ΤΟΥ κ.ΓΟΥΙΛΟΜΠΙ"
    cmdsrv.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

This is the result in the database: `2?? ???S?/?? ?????? ??? ?.G????????`.

If, on the other hand, I use the below query to update the record, the data will be inserted correctly.

```vb
Dim strsql = "UPDATE TBLSTK SET ICDESC='2ΤΟ ΧΡΙΣΤ/ΚΟ ΔΕΝΤΡΟ ΤΟΥ κ.ΓΟΥΙΛΟΜΠΙ' WHERE ITEMNO=27227"

Using cmdsrv As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("", myConn)
    cmdsrv.CommandText = strsql
    cmdsrv.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

This is the result in the database:

```
2ΤΟ ΧΡΙΣΤ/ΚΟ ΔΕΝΤΡΟ ΤΟΥ κ.ΓΟΥΙΛΟΜΠΙ
```

Comment: Is it unicode for greek characters right? If yes you need to add Character Set=unicode to your connectionstring and it should do the job

Comment: According to https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_datatype#RSQL_datatype_intcodes: _Caché also supports Unicode SQL types for ODBC applications working with multibyte character sets...To activate this functionality, refer to “Creating a DSN by Using the Control Panel” in Using Caché with ODBC_ . See also: https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_datatype#RSQL_datatype_intcodes . The following may also be helpful: https://blog.devart.com/installing-odbc-driver-and-creating-data-source-on-windows.html

Comment: There appears to be a native provider, probably better than ODBC. https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=TVQS_CONNECTINGDOTNET